# AngularJS: link function is not being passed a Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive:

```
     return {
            restrict: 'A', // Attribute Directive
            ngModel: '^ngModel',
            scope: {
                'ngModel': '='
            },
            link: function ($scope: ng.IScope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                var datePickerOptions = {
                    autoclose: true,
                    format: attrs.aceDatepickerFormat,
                    weekStart: attrs.aceDatepickerWeekstart
                };

                // Attach the datepicker events (must have Bootstrap.DatePicker referenced).
                element.datepicker(datePickerOptions).next().on('click', function () {
                    $(this).prev().focus();
                });

                element.click(() => {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(new Date());
                });
            }
        };
```

In this example, when the click event occurs on the element, I wish to use ctrl.$setViewValue to the current date (this is a test).

When the link function is called, scope, element and atts are all populated correctly, however the ctrl is null.

The element is with a div with ng-controller set.

```
<div ng-controller="Controllers.FormElementsController">
    <input class="form-control date-picker" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text"
           ng-model="DatePickerValue"
           ace-datepicker-weekstart="1"
           ace-datepicker-format="dd-mm-yyyy"
           ace-datepicker="" />

</div>
```

Why is no controller being passed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `require` to pull in the controller (`ngModelController` in your case):

```
return {
            restrict: 'A', // Attribute Directive
            require: '^ngModel',
```

You had it set to `ngModel` as the property name.

From [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The myPane directive has a require option with value ^myTabs. When a
>   directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the
>   specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means that this directive
>   searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the
>   directive would look for the controller on just its own element).